# Ploting points over image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot image and points over it. Unfortunately it does not work as expected:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from imageio import imread

img = imread('imageio:chelsea.png')
mx, my = img.shape[:2]
P = np.array([(0,0),(mx,0),(0,my),(mx,my),(100,100)])
plt.imshow(img)
plt.plot(P[:,0], P[:,1], 'o')
```

[image]

The reason is that imshow flips axes, but later plot don't take it into account.
I know that i can `plt.plot(P[:,1], P[:,0], 'o')` but it is not relay a solution.

**Is there way to flip axes permanently? Or any other solution?**

Comment: I think if you flip the plot and imshow, it should work. If you want, I can replicate the code in an answer, and show the results. :)

Comment: @gnahum Yes please

Answer (score 0):

The order of dimensions in `img` is not as you assume. `img[i][j]` refers to *row* `i` and *column* `j`. Therefore, you should write

```
my, mx = img.shape[:2]
```

Comment: This will make a mess, really terrible mess

Comment: Not exactly @majkrzak. If you plot with `plt.imshow(img, origin='lower')`, you'll see that axis are not being flipped, but that the vertical axes points downward and not upward (default behaviour if origin='upper'). You can control better the behavior of imshow using origin and extent, see here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html.

Comment: even with orign lower x axis is fliped with y

Comment: The axis are not being flipped. That's the standard way of representing matrices: `n` rows, `m` columns and the (0,0) at the top left. For images, it's `n` rows, `m` columns and `k` channels. If you decide that `n==x` and `m==y`, then it's your choice of representing the image, and you have to deal with it, but axis are never flipped.

Comment: This leeds to the situation where I(p) is not under the p on plot, and also propagate further to the applied transformation and so on. I love python word of ducks 

Comment: Not just Python, but any language (C, Java, ...) where 2D arrays are represented with the standard matrix notation.